Given a metric space $X$, is there a natural way to view the quasi-isometry group $QI(X)$ as a topological group?
Given a metric space $(X,d)$, we define $QI(X)$ as the set of quasi-isometries $f : X \to X$, modulo the equivalence relation
$$
f \sim g  \ \ \ \ \text{ if and only if } \ \ \  \sup_{x \in X} \ d(f(x),g(x)) < \infty.
$$
This set admits an obvious group structure via composition.
The group of isometries $Isom(X)$ is often viewed as a topological group. My question is then: is there ever a natural way to equip $QI(X)$ with a topology, perhaps for specific 'nice' $X$?
Thanks
